# Netbeans исправить buind .xml для новых проектов

Tags: java, netbeans

Хочу чтобы для всех новых проектов Java в Netbeans build.xml 
содержал данный код и не приходилось добавлять его при создании проекта
(Собирает все библиотеки в jar и копирует текстовые файлы из корня в папку store проекта)

```
<target name="-post-jar">

<!-- Change the value to the name of the final jar without .jar -->
<property name="store.jar.name" value="${application.title}"/>

<!-- don't edit below this line -->
<property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
<property name="temp.dir" value="temp"/>
<property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

<echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

<delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>
<mkdir dir="${temp.dir}"/>

<jar destfile="${temp.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
    <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
    <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>

<delete dir="${store.dir}"/>

<zip destfile="${store.jar}">
    <zipfileset src="${temp.dir}/temp_final.jar"
    excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
</zip>

    <copy todir="${store.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="*.ini,*.sql,*.txt"/>
    </copy>
<delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>
</target>
```